# Odd Things of ASP.NET MVC Deployment on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

Recently, I am a bit interested in the deployment of [ASP.NET MVC application on IIS6](http://www.cnblogs.com/misaxi/archive/2011/01/29/odd-things-of-aspnet-mvc-deployment-on-iis6.html) because **Phil Haack** posted an [easier way](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) to deploy ASP.NET MVC application on ASP.NET 4. So I decided to see how different version of ASP.NET MVC works on different version of ASP.NET.
First off, I created an ASP.NET MVC 2 project in Visual Studio 2010 and deploy it to IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 (only .NET framework 3.5 installed). I set the application to run in ASP.NET 2.0 and no extra stuff. Because I just wanted to see what sort of error would occur. And as expected, some error was reported as following.

[image]

Then, I set the Copy Local attribute of *System.Web.Mvc* assembly to *true* as following and deploy again.

[image]

As a result, the application ran smoothly.

[image]

I had read tons of materials talked about the mess of deploying MVC application on IIS 6. And I did fight to tackle the deploying issues in my previous project. At least, if had used **Extensionless Url** in your application, you should have configured wildcard mapping in IIS. But in this case, I even didn’t have chance to do so.

[image]

What the heck was going on exactly? Did I discover a new continent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your IIS is configured with a wildcard module mapping. With other words, the request path ".*" is being send to the asp.net ISAPI module.

Comment: Gidon, thanks for your response. Is that ".*" a default mapping in IIS? My test subject machine a clean one. I will check it when I am back home.